# Equivalent notion of completion of metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry, complete-spaces

In my introductory Topology course, a *completion* of a metric space $(X,d)$ is a complete metric space $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{d})$ together with an isometry $i : (X, d) \rightarrow (\tilde{X}, \tilde{d})$ with the following property:

For every complete metric space $(Y, d_Y)$ and every isometry $f : (X, d) \rightarrow (Y, d_Y)$ there exists a unique isometry $g : (\tilde{X}, \tilde{d}) \rightarrow (Y, d_Y)$ satisfying $f = g ∘ i$.

I want to show that $((\tilde{X}, \tilde{d}), i)$  is a completion of $(X, d)$ if and only if $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{d})$ is complete, $i$ is an isometry *and* $i[X]$ is dense in $\tilde{X}$. For "$\Rightarrow$", suppose $i[X]$ is not dense in $\tilde{X}$.  As $\overline{i[X]}$ is closed in $\tilde{X}$, and $\tilde{X}$ is complete, $\overline{i[X]}$ is complete. Thus it can take the role of the complete space $Y$ in the above definition. Thus, letting $Y := \overline{i[X]}$  and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ any isometry, I am looking for the contradiction that I can now find *more than one* isometry $g : \tilde{X} \rightarrow Y$ satisfying $f = g ∘ i$. Can I construct such $g$, or is this not a feasible strategy?

Comment: You cannot find a single isometry $X' \to Y$ if $i[X]$ isn't dense.

Comment: I see, that would work too. But why is it true?

Comment: See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i[X]$ where not dense in $(\tilde{X}, \tilde{d})$, pick $p$ in $\tilde{X}$ not in the closure of $i[X]$. We know $r>0$ exists so that $B_{\tilde{d}}(p,r) \cap i[X] = \emptyset$.

Define $Y=\overline{i[X]}$ in the restricted metric $d_Y$ from $\tilde{d}$, and note it is a complete metric space (being closed in one) and $f=i$ is well-defined isometry from $(X,d)$ to $(Y,d_Y)$. Now suppose an isometry $g: (\tilde{X}, \tilde{d}) \to (Y,d_Y)$ completing the diagram (so $g \circ i = f$) existed, then where can $p$ go?

$g(p) \in Y$ so lies (in $\tilde{X}$) in the closure of $i[X]$, so for some $x_0 \in X$, $\tilde{d}(i(x_0), g(p)) < r$.

But $i(x_0)= f(x_0) = g(i(x_0))$ and then $d_Y(g(p), g(i(x_0)) < r$ while we knew $\tilde{d}(p, i(x_0)) \ge r$, so $g$ is not an isometry.

So $i[X]$ has to be dense in $\tilde{X}$.

Comment: Very clear, thanks! For the converse I'm trying to construct $g : \tilde{X} \rightarrow Y$. For $x ∈ i[X]$ it's easy: just take $g(x) = f(i^{-1}(x))$. Any $x ∈ ∂i[X]$ is the limit of a sequence $(i(x_n))_n$ in $i[X]$. However, the 'original' sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $X$ need not converge in $X$, so we cannot apply the same trick. Thoughts how to proceed?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman a convergent sequence is Cauchy and Cauchyness is preserved by isometries and all relevant spaces are complete...

Comment: Is $X$ not relevant then..? i.e. how can we define g on $\overline{i[X]} \setminus i[X]$ without referring to $X$?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Let $p \in \overline{i[X]}$ and pick any sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $i(x_n) \to p$. Then this sequence is Cauchy in $(X,d)$ (as $i$ is an isometry) and so given $f: (X,d) \to (Y, d_Y$, an isometry, then $(f(x_n))_n$ is Cauchy and hence has a unique limit $q\in Y$. Then define $g(p)=q$. Check that $q$ does not depend on the choice of sequence and then $gi=f$ easily follows. Unicity of $g$ flows from $i[X]$ being dense etc.

Comment: Aaahh yes, this completely circumvents my problem, beautiful!