# Isometries on complete metric spaces map to dense subspaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $X$ be a complete metric space, and let $Y ⊆ X$ be a metric subspace. Suppose $g: X \rightarrow Y$ is an isometry. Does this imply that $\bar{Y} = X$? i.e. that $Y$ is dense in $X$?

Suppose that $Y$ is not dense in $X$, i.e. that $g$ maps $X$ onto a proper subset of itself. Now $g$ is an isometry, and therefore injective. In the case where $X$ is finite this would give a contradiction, but in the infinite case I do not see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X=[0,\infty)$ and $g(x)=x+1$, then $g$ is an isometry, but the image is $Y=[1,\infty)$, which is not dense in $X$.

Note that, in fact, $Y$ must be closed in $X$, since $g^{-1}$ maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. Hence, if $y_n=g(x_n)$ in $Y$ converges to $y$ in $X$, then $x_n$ is Cauchy with limit $x$. However, this gives $$
g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} g(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n=y$$

So $Y$ is simply a subspace of $X$ which is isometrically isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: You're right, of course. But then I don't understand the first comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530635/equivalent-notion-of-completion-of-metric-space?noredirect=1#comment7261591_3530635

Comment: It's a bit confusing to read as you seem to be changing notation in the phrasing your question (I'm assuming that your completion $\overline{X}$ and $X'$ denote the same space). However, you've got the arrows around wrong. The commenter says $i:X\to X'$ should have dense image in order to fulfill the universal property. This question would be about a map $g:X'\to X$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I've edited accordingly. Still trying to figure out the rest.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain (there) why the commenter claims that? 

Comment: No idea. It's not true. Say $X=(1,\infty)$ and $X'=[0,\infty)$, then the usual inclusion is an isometry, but $X'$ is, again, isometrically isomorphic to the completion of $X$.